# Hi. I'm a beginner so I need help to solve this equations using Regula-Falsi to find root of the equation (which is x)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, programming, equation-solving

I've been trying to look for an example but only with one unknown. In my case of studies, I have 4 unknowns. I just want to make sure is it correct the way I'm writing the coding to find the root which is x. After that, I'm going to use numerical integration (Trapezoidal rule) to solve the integral. Thank you so much for the reply.

```
 RegulaFalsi[a0_, b0_, q_] := 
 Module[{}, a = N[a0]; b = N[b0]; c = (a*f[b] - b*f[a])/(f[b] - f[a]);
   j = 0;
  output = {{j, a, c, b, f[c]}};
  While[j < q, If[Sign[f[b]] == Sign[f[c]], b = c, a = c;];
   c = (a*f[b] - b*f[a])/(f[b] - f[a]);
   j = j + 1;
   output = Append[output, {j, a, c, b, f[c]}];];
  Print[NumberForm[
    TableForm[output, 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"j", "aj", "cj", "bj", "f[cj]"}}], 15]];
  Print[" c=", NumberForm[c, 15]];
  Print[" f[c]=", NumberForm[f[c], 15]];]

f[x_] = ((x (x + y) - r^2)/r)^n - 
   n y ((x (x + y) - r^2)/r)^(n - 1) - ((r^2 - x (x + y))/r)^n + 
   n y ((r^2 - x (x + y))/r)^(n - 1);
RegulaFalsi[-1, 1, 15]
```

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! I haven't looked at the rest, but to start, your syntax for `Module` is off: all of the local variables for `Module` need to be listed in the first argument list, which in your case is empty. So, `Module[{a = N[a0], b = N[b0], c, j = 0, output}, ...]`. (Note that they are separated as list elements with commas, not semicolons. Note also that you can choose to initialize the variables in the binding list, or not. You might choose not to if they depend on other local variables, such as `c` and `output`.)

Comment: Thanks Dear Thorimur for the correction. I change already as advised RegulaFalsi[a0_, b0_, q_] := Module[{a = N[a0], b = N[b0], c = (a*f[b] - b*f[a])/(f[b] - f[a]), j = 0, output = {{j, a, c, b, f[c]}}},.....] However, the answer seems to be the same even as you said the syntax for Module is empty. Could you please clarify on the working to get the root when using 4 unknowns. Thank you.